# Handling SIGINT or KeyboardInterrupt in Python 3 to exit gracefully using a "with socket" block

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, sigint

For a project where I am dumping data over tcp through a secured network, I am trying to write a development test server to streamline the testing process. I have the server, which basically just takes data and prints it to the terminal.

However, I am unhappy with my current implementation of sigint handling.

I tried using signal handlers, and try/except/finally blocks in various configurations to no avail.

Here's the code for the test server

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import socket
import sys

host = ''
port = 5000
try:
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.bind((host, port))
        s.listen(1)
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            print("Connected by", str(addr))
            while True:
                data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
                if not data:
                    break
                print(str(data))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Quitting...")
finally:
    sys.exit()
```

This version exits without a stack trace... and well, nothing else.

Here are the things I tried, and the problems:

- use a global "listening" variable (while listening) instead of the while True, in which case a sigint handler would set the variable to false. This meant that if the tcp socket never accepted any data, it would not terminate at all with a sigint, and a sigquit or sigkill was necessary
- use a try catch block in the while True block, or just before it. Once again, this didn't actually help with anything before the connection is already accepted.
- use a try catch for the entire primary with block. This means that I can only exit, and fake a graceful shutdown, while in reality it is not. Also, I believe it goes against the principle of using the with block to begin with. (and I'm not sure if this approach closes the socket, or if that is even necessary)

Comment: I'm not seeing what's wrong with your current implementation. When I run your code, and type Ctrl-C, it prints "Quitting..." and exits; and it runs this way before or after the `accept`. And the context managers cause both sockets to be closed when it hits the `KeyboardInterrupt` except block. What else are you looking to do?

Comment: @GilHamilton I was thinking that my solution feels a bit hackish, and just pretends to gracefully quit while the only thing it does is avoid printing a stack trace. Perhaps I am being overly critical in such a simple application, and I don't have a way to reliably test that the with blocks actually complete fully (such as if the print command was actually a long running data processing pipeline, would it complete and gracefully quit?) so I wanted someone else's eyes on it.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of options here, depending on what exactly your concerns are. As written now... No, if your `print` was instead a long set of operations, it would *not* necessarily complete if you typed Ctrl-C.

One thing you can do is to temporarily block the `SIGINT` signal with `signal.pthread_sigmask` if, say, you're in the middle of a critical operation you don't want interrupted, then unmask it afterwards (at which point, the `SIGINT` will flow through to the `KeyboardInterrupt` as usual). That can also be implemented via a context manager as shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import signal

class SignalMasker:
    """ Temporarily block signals. """
    def __init__(self, sigs):
        self.sigs = set(sigs)
    def __enter__(self):
        signal.pthread_sigmask(signal.SIG_BLOCK, self.sigs)
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        signal.pthread_sigmask(signal.SIG_UNBLOCK, self.sigs)
        return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    interrupted = True
    try:
        with SignalMasker([signal.SIGINT]):
            # Should not be able to interrupt this before 5 seconds expired
            time.sleep(5)
            interrupted = False
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nGot keyboard interrupt")
        assert not interrupted
```

If the only thing you're ensuring is that the file descriptors are closed and avoiding the stack trace, then what you have now is fine.